# Flex or flash table-like object with expanding rows

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, datagrid

I've recently just started delving into both actionscript and flex...the main reason being I like to create a sortable datagrid or datagroup like this (http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/expandable-rows/) where you click the main entry that already has some detail and the row expands to show more.

It might be possible to do with an itemrenderer but for the life of me I cant seem to find any tutorial or source or demo that doesn't assume you already know what to do with the itemrenderer since you cant just drop them in and have them work it seems.

Any advice on how to go about doing this or links to some tutorials to help me find my own way would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, well..there are better examples I could have linked to but that was the one I had bookmarked.  There are plenty of jquery tables out there though that have sortable columns and expandable rows.  Were it just the accordion functionality I was looking for I'd be set...but its both the expanding rows and the sorting I need.

Thank you for the links though, I will look at them and see if I cant fill any gaps in my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you link to looks more like an [Accordion](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Accordion) than a DataGrid.  I'd start by looking at that.

If you want to try to create something like that and specify a dataProvider; I would look into using a [List](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/List.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) not a DataGrid.  Use an itemRenderer and be sure to set [variableRowHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#variableRowHeight) to true.  There is also a [WindowShade](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/flexlib/containers/WindowShade.html) component in [Flexlib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/) which you may want to use as the base of your itemRenderer class.

Answer (score 0):

The FlexLib window shade is very good. We use a Collapsible Panel here, very similar to this one http://hasseg.org/stuff/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanelDemo.swf

Comment: That does look good actually...now is it sortable somehow or would I have to force that myself?

Comment: You could do it yourself. Maybe store each panel in an arrayCollection, and sort the ArrayCollection by whatever panel attributes you want. Then have a function that adds the panels to a VBox or something in the order in which they're stored in the ArrayCollection. If I had time, I'd love to try this. If you get it working, will you  post the code?

Comment: Of course, Brian.  It might be awhile before I figure it out though given I dont even know about ArrayCollections and whatnot.  I only started in this a couple of days ago and for all the googling...most of the resources I've found assume you know what you are doing with the code rather then how to code.  Slowly learning though.

Comment: As you see things you dont understand, especially with regard to Object Oriented aspects of Flex, look them up. The OOP side is where a lot of mistakes/problems are made/occur